# Angular 2 button type submit wont work

Tags: html, angular, onclick

I am working on the html part. the button with button type "submit" doesnt work in my project.

app.component.html

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-offset-2 col-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="myFunction()"> Submits </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>


function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is a virtually meaningless problem description and makes no mention of errors thrown. Not sure why you would use native `onclick` in angular app to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with angular you can add an event click to your button by adding:

```
(click)="yourfunction()"
```

but you can use the forms module or the reactive forms module to access the property of your form like that:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSignin(form)" #form="ngForm">
    <!-- your forms data here -->
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

and then implement your form in the ts file like that:

```
onSignin(form: NgForm) { 
    // execute your code here
  }
```